# Change the specified cell in the data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like below:

```
0       INT_ID  F1_ID  chr  start   T1    T2
1  F143-F44837    143    1   5000   True  True
2    F144-F153    144    1  15000   True  True
3    F152-F153    152    1  20000   True  True
4    F152-F175    152    2  25000   True  True
5    F152-F175    152    3  40000   True  True
```

and I want to change a particular cell.
for example :

if F1_ID==144  and start==15000 then T1 should be False.

how can I change a cell in data frame pandas in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` and your conditions. It is important to use `loc` to [avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas).

```
df.loc[df['F1_ID'].eq(144) & df['start'].eq( 15000), 'T1'] = False
```

output:

```
   0       INT_ID  F1_ID  chr  start     T1    T2
0  1  F143-F44837    143    1   5000   True  True
1  2    F144-F153    144    1  15000  False  True
2  3    F152-F153    152    1  20000   True  True
3  4    F152-F175    152    2  25000   True  True
4  5    F152-F175    152    3  40000   True  True
```